# Does angular js have support for the HTML5 formdata object

Tags: angularjs, http, form-data

I have been searching and I can't seem to find any articles on how to post formdata with angular.  I don't want to upload a file I want to post text data as objects and then. does the $http module support posting using formdata instead of application/x-www-form-urlencoded?

Comment: your `instead of` is incorrect....default $http post is json...and yes of course formData is supported...angular is javascript. There are numerous upload directives you can look into

Comment: how would you write the code?

Comment: really simple google search to get started  `angular upload` ... lots of results

Comment: also keep inmind that `$http` is a wrapper (with lots of extras) for `XMLHttpRequest`

Comment: I will take a look and update my code and post it if I can't get it to work

Answer (score 0):

You can use formdata normally as any other data in your post request.

see the below example

```
    var formData = new FormData();

    formData.append('key1', 'hello');
    formData.append('key2', 'hi');

    $http.post('https://some.com/post-here',formdata, {
        headers: { 'Content-Type': false },
        transformRequest: function(data) { 
            return data; 
        }
    }).then(function() {
        alert('success');
    }, function() {
        alert('error');
    })
```